# How to add a new project in Trac via Bitanami hosting

Tags: trac, bitnami

I have launched a TRAC demo server in cloud using Bitnami hosting. I just want to check how to work with multiple projects in TRAC. Now I can see only one project in the demo server and no options are there to add new project.

Bitnami wiki explains how to create a new project in windows/mac via cmd but I can't find any info about project creation in cloud. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not fully clear what you understand of "projects"; that term is ambiguous. But there are 2 possibilities:

On the level of Apache and its Trac instances:

- bitnami-trac-1.0.1\apache2\conf\httpd.conf contains an include of bitnami-trac-1.0.1\apps\trac\conf\trac.conf and you can add another `<Location>` of a new Trac instance there. This will allow to run multiple Tracs within one Apache. See this [Trac wiki about MultipleProject](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/Proposals/MultipleProject) for details. Basically, first you need to create a second Trac instance (with its database) by calling `bitnami-trac-1.0.1\apps\trac\Scripts\trac-admin.exe` from Bitnami command line shell.

On the level of Trac and its plugins:

- you may want to setup several "user projects" within one running Trac instance. Read this [Trac wiki about MultipleProjects/SingleEnvironment](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMultipleProjects/SingleEnvironment#Plugin%20solution) for details. Basically, you'll need to install and setup a plugin called SimpleMultiProjectPlugin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access your machine and use the command line. Take a look at the documentantion for accessing your server: http://wiki.bitnami.com/BitNami_Cloud_Hosting/Servers/Access_your_machine